# How to change the DataTable Column Name?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net, datatable

I have one DataTable which has four columns such as

```
 StudentID        CourseID          SubjectCode            Marks    
------------     ----------        -------------          --------
    1               100              MT400                  80
    2               100              MT400                  79
    3               100              MT400                  88
```

Here I am inserting this Datatable into the Sql server table by passing this datatable as an XML Table.

I just want to Change the DataTable Column Name "Marks" as "SubjectMarks" and pass this DataTable as an XML Table.

I know how to pass the DataTable as an XML Table. But I dont know, How to change the DataTable Column Name "Marks" as "SubjectMarks".

Answer (score 301, accepted):

Try this:

```
dataTable.Columns["Marks"].ColumnName = "SubjectMarks";
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this solution but somehow my data gets lost when I change the column name.

Comment: I just tried this solution now and it works fine - it did not do any changes or wipe out the underlying column data. Maybe something else is happening in your code...

Comment: what if the original name 'Marks' can contain whitespace?

Answer (score 31):

Rename the Column by doing the following:

```
dataTable.Columns["ColumnName"].ColumnName = "newColumnName";
```

Answer (score 8):

Use:

```
dt.Columns["Name"].ColumnName = "xyz";
dt.AcceptChanges();
```

or

```
dt.Columns[0].ColumnName = "xyz";
dt.AcceptChanges();
```

Answer (score 6):

```
 dtTempColumn.Columns["EXCELCOLUMNS"].ColumnName = "COLUMN_NAME";                        
 dtTempColumn.AcceptChanges();
```

Comment: What does your additional code do here? Adding comments would help.

Answer (score 1):

after generating XML you can just Replace your `XML <Marks>... content here </Marks>` tags with `<SubjectMarks>... content here </SubjectMarks>tag`. and pass updated XML to your DB.

Your XML Generate Like as below.

```
<NewDataSet>
      <StudentMarks> 
          <StudentID>1</StudentID>
          <CourseID>100</CourseID>
          <SubjectCode>MT400</SubjectCode>
          <Marks>80</Marks>
      </StudentMarks>
      <StudentMarks> 
          <StudentID>1</StudentID>
          <CourseID>100</CourseID>
          <SubjectCode>MT400</SubjectCode>
          <Marks>79</Marks>
      </StudentMarks>
      <StudentMarks> 
          <StudentID>1</StudentID>
          <CourseID>100</CourseID>
          <SubjectCode>MT400</SubjectCode>
          <Marks>88</Marks>
      </StudentMarks>
  </NewDataSet>
```

Here you can assign XML to string variable like as

```
string strXML = DataSet.GetXML();

strXML = strXML.Replace ("<Marks>","<SubjectMarks>");
strXML = strXML.Replace ("<Marks/>","<SubjectMarks/>");
```

and now pass strXML To your DB.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
"columns": [
{data: "id", name: "aaa", sortable: false},
{data: "userid", name: "userid", sortable: false},
{data: "group_id", name: "group_id", sortable: false},
{data: "group_name", name: "group_name", sortable: false},
{data: "group_member", name: "group_member"},
{data: "group_fee", name: "group_fee"},
{data: "dynamic_type", name: "dynamic_type"},
{data: "dynamic_id", name: "dynamic_id"},
{data: "content", name: "content", sortable: false},
{data: "images", name: "images", sortable: false},
{data: "money", name: "money"},
{data: "is_audit", name: "is_audit", sortable: false},
{data: "audited_at", name: "audited_at", sortable: false}
```

]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
dataTable.Columns["OldColumnName"].ColumnName = "NewColumnName";
```