# How to Change the Header Name / Column Name Of a Datatable Fed to dataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

I am using `DataTable` to fill a `DataGridView` for a search / filter.

The DataGridView shows the actual Database column names.

But I want to change those column names. eg `tbl_Users` has a column labeled `LocalNo` that I want to change to `Unit No.`

Here is my **code**:

```
namespace FrequencyBook
{
public partial class Form11 : Form
{
    private static Form11 alreadyOpened = null;
    public Form11()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        {
            if (alreadyOpened != null && !alreadyOpened.IsDisposed)

            {
                alreadyOpened.Focus();            // Bring the old one to top
                Shown += (s, e) => this.Close();  // and destroy the new one.
                return;
            }

            // Otherwise store this one as reference
            alreadyOpened = this;
        }
    }

    private DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    private void Form11_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView11.DataSource = GetSearchForm();
    }


    private DataTable GetSearchForm()
    {
        string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FrequencyBook.Properties.Settings.db_FrequenciesConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString))

        {
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * FROM tbl_Users", conn))

            {
                conn.Open();
                OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                dt.Load(reader);
            }
        }

        return dt;
    }

    private void closeFormToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void resetFormToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tboxSearchLicensee.Clear();
        tboxSearchCallsign.Clear();
        tboxSearchLocation.Clear();
        tboxSearchBand.Clear();
        tboxSearchRID.Clear();
        tboxSearchLocalNo.Clear();
    }

    private void tboxSearchLicensee_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
        dv.RowFilter = "Licensee LIKE '%" + tboxSearchLicensee.Text + "%'" ;
    }

    private void tboxSearchCallsign_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
        dv.RowFilter = "Callsign LIKE '%" + tboxSearchCallsign.Text + "%'" ;
    }

    private void tboxSearchLocation_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
        dv.RowFilter = "Location LIKE '%" + tboxSearchLocation.Text + "%'" ;
    }

    private void tboxSearchBand_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
        dv.RowFilter = "Band LIKE '%" + tboxSearchBand.Text + "%'" ;
    }

    private void tboxSearchRID_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
        dv.RowFilter = string.Format("RID1 LIKE '%{0}%' OR RID2 LIKE '%{0}%' OR RID3 LIKE '%{0}%' OR RID4 LIKE '%{0}%'", tboxSearchRID.Text);

        //DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
        //dv.RowFilter = "RID1 LIKE '%" + tboxSearchRID.Text + "%'" ;
    }

    private void tboxSearchLocalNo_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
        dv.RowFilter = "LocalNo LIKE '%" + tboxSearchLocalNo.Text + "%'" ;
    }
```

I've read this post here: 
[How to change the DataTable Column Name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6407239/how-to-change-the-datatable-column-name)
The first answer makes sense to me, but I don't know where I need to add the new lines. I've tried in a few places, but NO JOY.

Comment: You can change the Column Name as mentioned in the link in the GetSearchForm, right before your return "dt". You can also do it in the Form_Load. You need to assign the value returned by GetSearchForm to a variable, and before you set the DataSource, you can change the Column names

Comment: You could change the `dataGridView1.Columns[N].HeaderText = "[SomethingElse]";`. Using some source to match the pairs: `DataColumn[N].ColumnName -> DGV.Column[N].HeaderText`. It looks like you're just filtering the rows.

Comment: Thank you Anu. I knew it would work, but I kept putting it in the wrong place and I was not changing DataTable.Columns to dt.Columns. Worked perfect before the return dt; ..... Thank you again

Comment: Actually @Anu Viswan, I did find a problem. While your solution does address and fix the header names, nothing happens when I fill in the actual form with search terms. It's obviously because of the dv.RowFilter lines below.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my new code. It works for the header / column name change, but it breaks the actual search / filter function. I actually changed the new lines back to the original name and got the Form to work again. Any suggestions? Here is a screenshot of my Search / Filter Form:
[My search form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Fxjq.jpg)

```
namespace FrequencyBook
{
public partial class Form11 : Form
{
    private static Form11 alreadyOpened = null;
    public Form11()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        {
            if (alreadyOpened != null && !alreadyOpened.IsDisposed)

            {
                alreadyOpened.Focus();            // Bring the old one to top
                Shown += (s, e) => this.Close();  // and destroy the new one.
                return;
            }

            // Otherwise store this one as reference
            alreadyOpened = this;
        }
    }

    private DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    private void Form11_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView11.DataSource = GetSearchForm();
    }


    private DataTable GetSearchForm()
    {
        string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FrequencyBook.Properties.Settings.db_FrequenciesConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString))

        {
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * FROM tbl_Users", conn))

            {
                conn.Open();
                OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                dt.Load(reader);
            }
        }
        dt.Columns["ID"].ColumnName = "ID";
        dt.Columns["Licensee"].ColumnName = "Licensee";
        dt.Columns["Callsign"].ColumnName = "Callsign";
        dt.Columns["LocalNo"].ColumnName = "Unit";
        dt.Columns["Location"].ColumnName = "Location";
        dt.Columns["FreqBand"].ColumnName = "Band";
        dt.Columns["Email"].ColumnName = "Email";
        dt.Columns["Phone"].ColumnName = "Phone";
        dt.Columns["RID1"].ColumnName = "RID1";
        dt.Columns["RID2"].ColumnName = "RID2";
        dt.Columns["RID3"].ColumnName = "RID3";
        dt.Columns["RID4"].ColumnName = "RID4";
        dt.Columns["Notes"].ColumnName = "Notes";

        return dt;
    }

    private void closeFormToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void resetFormToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tboxSearchLicensee.Clear();
        tboxSearchCallsign.Clear();
        tboxSearchLocation.Clear();
        tboxSearchBand.Clear();
        tboxSearchRID.Clear();
        tboxSearchLocalNo.Clear();
    }

    private void tboxSearchLicensee_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
        dv.RowFilter = "Licensee LIKE '%" + tboxSearchLicensee.Text + "%'" ;
    }

    private void tboxSearchCallsign_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
        dv.RowFilter = "Callsign LIKE '%" + tboxSearchCallsign.Text + "%'" ;
    }

    private void tboxSearchLocation_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
        dv.RowFilter = "Location LIKE '%" + tboxSearchLocation.Text + "%'" ;
    }

    private void tboxSearchBand_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
        dv.RowFilter = "Band LIKE '%" + tboxSearchBand.Text + "%'" ;
    }

    private void tboxSearchRID_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
        dv.RowFilter = string.Format("RID1 LIKE '%{0}%' OR RID2 LIKE '%{0}%' OR RID3 LIKE '%{0}%' OR RID4 LIKE '%{0}%'", tboxSearchRID.Text);

        //DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
        //dv.RowFilter = "RID1 LIKE '%" + tboxSearchRID.Text + "%'" ;
    }

    private void tboxSearchLocalNo_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataView dv = dt.DefaultView;
        dv.RowFilter = "Unit LIKE '%" + tboxSearchLocalNo.Text + "%'" ;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //This button has changed to btnReturnToUsers
        this.Hide();//Hide the 'current' form,  form11 
                    //show another form ( form12 )   
        Form12 frm = new Form12();
        frm.ShowDialog();
        //Close the form.(form11)
        this.Close();
    }

    private void btnReturnToMain_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();//Hide the 'current' form,  form11 
                    //show another form ( form2 )   
        Form2 frm = new Form2();
        frm.ShowDialog();
        //Close the form.(form11)
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

}