# Map column names from a datatable to another datatable in C#

Tags: c#

I would like to map a datatable column names from another datatable. Please refer below example. I have 2 datatables returned from database.

[image]

[image]

Please see above 2 tables. The first table contains data and second datatable contains column mapping.
I would like to map column names from second table to first table. The final result should be as below.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the DataTable Column Name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6407239/how-to-change-the-datatable-column-name)

Comment: What genius chose that schema design?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a SQL statement dynamically and end up with:

```
Select column1 as city, column2 as country,
column3 as population, column4 as tourist
from whatever_table
```